# How CSS specificity affects site performance & page load time

Tags: css, performance, css-specificity

please look for 2 websites:

- http://kutra.pl/id/id.html
- http://kutra.pl/class/class.html

**Both were prepared with similar HTML, one CSS stylesheest, and 6 identical images.**

In first case, inside CSS, a lot of elements are selected with `#selector`.
In second, I changed most of (sth about 70%) selectors to `.selector`

Using http://www.webpagetest.org I prepared 9 tests for 1st & 2nd case (each pack of tests has been launched 3 times - so: 27 tests for each website). Results were very similar in both cases http://take.ms/IIo7w

[image]

So some questions in this topic:

1. Is it possible to CSS specificity has so big (~10%) affect on page load speed?
2. Do You have any online calculator for CSS specificity which can count global score for big stylesheets (for example > 2000 selectors)
3. Maybe someone knows why Star Render time is higher in .class selector case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your 2nd question, you can try this - https://isellsoap.github.io/specificity-visualizer/

Answer (score 2):

Specificity doesn't really affect performance. It's more a maintainability issue and handling precedence of styles applied. Use classes if you can since they are more maintainable.

If you want an article on the subject it's easy to find on google, but here is one for fun

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Ok, thanks - so, why have I got different results in 27 tests? The one & only difference between website was a CSS specificity of stylesheet. Do You have any idea?

Comment: I think there is a small difference, but that should drive your design. It's considered better practice to opt for the more maintainable classes over ids. The performance loss is negligible. Like you said in your question "the results are similar". Also think about why you would use a class. It's reusable so you can use it multiple times. Also ids have the highest specificty which can be problematic when you need another style to display. There are quite a lot of things to read up on around this. For example http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_idclass.htm

Comment: @MichałKutra Please mark as answer if you are happy with it. Thanks.